# CodeEffects rule editor throws an exception "No method with "[NULL]" value of the "token" attribute found" while saving the rule

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I am using the CodeEffects rule editor to create an editor which has dynamic actions and properties. Since the requirements are dynamic i used the FlexSource type option provided by CodeEffects in their document. But when i tried to save the rule using the same i am getting the exception.

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
CodeEffects.Rule.Common.SourceException: No method with "[NULL]" value of the "token" attribute found. (#112)
   at CodeEffects.Rule.Core.SourceLoader.GetMethodByToken(XmlNode sourceXml, String token, Boolean isMethod, ErrorIds errorTag, Type sourceObject)
   at CodeEffects.Rule.Core.RuleValidator.ValidateSourceSection(List`1 items, XmlDocument sourceXml, String sourceName, XmlDocument help, Boolean noActionsAllowed, List`1 list, Int32& i, Type sourceObject)
   at CodeEffects.Rule.Core.RuleValidator.DoValidate(XmlDocument help, List`1 items, XmlDocument source, Boolean noActionsAllowed, Type sourceObject)
   at CodeEffects.Rule.Core.RuleValidator.Validate(List`1 items, XmlDocument source, Boolean noActionsAllowed, Type sourceObject)
   at CodeEffects.Rule.Models.RuleModel.IsValid(GetRuleDelegate ruleDelegate)
   at CodeEffects.Rule.Web.RuleEditor.LoadClientData(String ruleClientData)
   at CodeEffect.FlexType.Controllers.HomeController.SaveRule(ClientRequest data) in /home/hbhudrani/Enviso/tmp/CodeEffect.FlexType/Controllers/HomeController.cs:line 65
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I also tried to check if the same thing happens in their demo project or it works fine.
So i converted their demo project source (found it here https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Demo-Project) into a .net core application as i am working with .net core application.
Apart of converting it i didn't change anything. After running the project i got the same exception.

Comment: Do your action methods have overloads?

Comment: No, there are different methods.

Answer (score 0):

The newest release fixes this issue. Update your NuGet references.